# flutter- put cursor on a textfield using local offset

Tags: flutter, textfield, offset

Flutter textfield automatically puts cursor on the desired position when one simply taps on it.
However, I do not know how to achieve this effect when the user clicks on it for the first time, since I am just making the textfield visible.
I have the local offset in which I would like to put my cursor on.  However, flutter only has the selection method, in which I have to know the number of text characters rather than the local offset.

```
contentTextController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
        TextPosition(offset: theoffsetnum,)
```

How can I put the cursor on the text that corresponds to the local offset within the textfield?